# ReportLab Add Multi-page PDF to Canvas

Tags: reportlab, pdf-reader, pdfrw

Using PdfReader along with ReportLab, I am attempting to pull in a PDF page, save it (both successful), then pull in a multi-page PDF and do the same.
I know how how to pull in a PDF one page at a time, but I'm struggling to pull in more than one page.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from pdfrw import PdfReader
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl

c = canvas.Canvas(Out_Folder+pdf_file_name)
c.setPageSize([11*inch, 8.5*inch])

page = PdfReader(folder+'2_VisionMissionValues.pdf',decompress=False).pages
p = pagexobj(page[0])
c.setPageSize([11*inch, 8.5*inch]) #Set page size (for landscape)
c.doForm(makerl(c, p))
c.showPage()

p3_ = PdfReader(m4folder+'Academy.pdf',decompress=False).pages
```

Here's where I'm lost. I know this works for just pulling in the first page....

```
p3 = pagexobj(p3_[0])
```

But if I want to pull in all pages of the PDF, I'm not sure what to do.
I tried this:

```
p3 = [pagexobj(x) for x in p3_[:]]
```

but it resulted in an Assertion Error (see below).

```
c.setPageSize([8.5*inch, 11*inch]) #Set page size (for portrait)
c.doForm(makerl(c, p3))
c.showPage()
c.save()


AssertionError: [{'/BBox': [0.0, 0.0, 792.0, 612.0], '/Filter': '/FlateDecode', '/FormType': 1, '/Matrix': [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0], '/Length': '56', '/Subtype': '/Form', '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/ImageB', '/ImageC', '/ImageI'], '/XObject': {'/Im1': (8, 0)}}, '/Type': '/XObject'}, {'/BBox': [0.0, 0.0, 792.0, 612.0], '/Filter': '/FlateDecode', '/FormType': 1, '/Matrix': [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0], '/Length': '56', '/Subtype': '/Form', '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/ImageB', '/ImageC', '/ImageI'], '/XObject': {'/Im2': (17, 0)}}, '/Type': '/XObject'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reportlab canvas only works on one page at a time, so you need to use the reportlab `doForm()` and `showPage()` functions once per output page, not on all the pages as a list.

**Edited to add**

I just remembered that I have some sample code that will copy a subset of the pages of a PDF file to an output file using reportlab [here](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/rl1/subset.py).  The inner loop does this:

```
for page in pages:
    canvas.setPageSize((page.BBox[2], page.BBox[3]))
    canvas.doForm(makerl(canvas, page))
    canvas.showPage()
```

For what it's worth, if you're only copying pages, you don't need reportlab; there is a similar subset example in the directory above that does it solely with pdfrw.

(Disclaimer:  I am the primary pdfrw author.)

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick Maupin! I have another issue which I'll post as a separate question.

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773477/reportlab-and-pdfrw-importing-scanned-pdf

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this answer would help in generating multiple pages on the same pdf file using Canvas.
Based on the Reportlab [userguide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) :

> The showPage method causes the canvas to stop drawing on the current
> page and any further operationswill draw on a subsequent page (if
> there are any further operations -- if not no new page is created).
> Thesave method must be called after the construction of the document
> is complete -- it generates the PDFdocument, which is the whole
> purpose of the canvas object.

Here, is a simple example.

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

def write(myfile, page_number):
    myfile.drawString(200, 600, 'Page number %i script' % page_number)

myfile = Canvas('multi_pages.pdf')
total_pages = 3

for i in range(total_pages):
    write(myfile, i)
    myfile.showPage()

myfile.save()
```